# Authenticating Social login with Firebase Auth and Express?

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm quite new to Firebase and slightly new to Express and I'm having a difficult time trying to use the authentication process Firebase offers.

I have this route, but everytime I click the button that triggers the route, I get this error `This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.`

I'm pretty sure web storage is enabled, but I'm quite unsure how to fix the `location.protocol`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the route:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', function(req, res) {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

[Here's the full Firebase app](https://gist.github.com/ErraticFox/44f7a8f95620f2e41e9cda59ec7ef89c)

Comment: is your platfrom IOS or Android or neither ?

Comment: @turmuka neither, it's a node express app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code.

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
Auth.$signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(authData) {
    // success
}).catch(function(error) {
    // error
});
```

Comment: That looks like Angular code. I'm not using Angular at the moment, as I'm testing with Firebase and trying to get familiar. As of right now, its solely express and firebase.

Comment: what is the version you are using for firebase? @Zevoxa

Comment: the latest on npm, 4.3.1. I updated the question with a link to the full apps code.

Comment: interesting case @Zevoxa I would say contact firebase support as they answer any question, i will make some search if i find anything I'll notice you

Comment: I think it has something to do with "web storage" being enabled. Do I have to stick that somewhere in a configuration file? As I logged `window.location.protocol` and it was `http:`